# Impelementation of RTCDataChannel of WebRTC in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webrtc

I am using [ISBX/apprtc-ios](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios) code for video chat implementation. This work perfect in iPhone and simulator. I want to send text/string data between two peers and I am using `RTCDataChannel` class.

Following is my implementation and I am not able to establish the connection. It always give the status `kRTCDataChannelStateConnecting` How can I get the RTCDataChannel connected? Is there any working implementation available for WebRTC RTCDataChannel for iOS?

```
- (void)createNewDataChannel {
    if (self.clientDataChannel) {
        switch(self.clientDataChannel.state) {
            case kRTCDataChannelStateConnecting:
                NSLog(@"kRTCDataChannelStateConnecting");
                break;
            case kRTCDataChannelStateOpen:
                NSLog(@"kRTCDataChannelStateOpen");
                break;
            case kRTCDataChannelStateClosing:
                NSLog(@"kRTCDataChannelStateClosing");
                break;
            case kRTCDataChannelStateClosed:
                NSLog(@"kRTCDataChannelStateClosed");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Unknown");
        }
        return;
    }
    if (self.peerConnection == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Peerconnection is nil");
    }

    RTCDataChannelInit *DataChannelInit = [[RTCDataChannelInit alloc] init];
    DataChannelInit.maxRetransmits = 0;
    DataChannelInit.isOrdered=false;
    DataChannelInit.maxRetransmitTimeMs = -1;
    DataChannelInit.isNegotiated = false;
    DataChannelInit.streamId = 25;
    RTCDataChannel *dataChannel =[_peerConnection createDataChannelWithLabel:@"commands" config:DataChannelInit];
    dataChannel.delegate=self;
    self.clientDataChannel = dataChannel;

    if (self.clientDataChannel == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Datachannel is nil");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Datachannel is working");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/Mahabali/Apprtc-swift ? I am sure its same as the web datachannel is webrtc? What response are you getting when you create a  data channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to send data through RTCDataChannel. What I did is before sending the offer. I created the RTCDataChannelInit with the below configuration.

```
RTCDataChannelInit *datainit = [[RTCDataChannelInit alloc] init];

datainit.isNegotiated = YES;

datainit.isOrdered = YES;

datainit.maxRetransmits = 30;

datainit.maxRetransmitTimeMs = 30000;

datainit.streamId = 1;
self.dataChannel = [_peerConnection createDataChannelWithLabel:@"commands" config:datainit];
self.dataChannel.delegate=self;
```

Once both the devices get connected, I checked the state in the delegate function. The state of the channel is open.

```
- (void)channelDidChangeState:(RTCDataChannel*)channel
{
    NSLog(@"channel.state %u",channel.state);
}
```

Then I send the data as per the below code:

```
RTCDataBuffer *buffer = [[RTCDataBuffer alloc] initWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] isBinary:NO];
BOOL x = [self.dataChannel sendData:buffer];
```

The configuration I used was given here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/discuss-webrtc/RTCDataChannel/discuss-webrtc/9NObqxnItCg/mRvXBIwkA7wJ

Comment: i am going through the webrtc tutorials point - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_sending_messages.html and implemented the data channel it's working fine on the web and on ios only receiving the message but not sending can you help me out

Comment: A sample based on @Jassi 's answer https://github.com/vincenzourbisaglia/apprtc-ios/commit/1173b58ae8a28fe6a1b6aa17b4b72dcaf23dfdc5